# How to access route parameter inside getServerSideProps in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, supabase

I want to query my Supabase table using the ID in the slug e.g. `localhost:3000/book/1` then show information about that book on the page in Next.js.

**Table**

[image]

**book/[id].js**

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { getBook } from '@/utils/supabase-client';

export default function Book({bookJson}) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query
  
  return <div>
    <p>Book: {id}</p>
    <h1>{bookJson}</h1>
  </div>
}

export async function getServerSideProps(query) {
  const id = 1 // Get ID from slug
  const book = await getBook(id);
  const bookJson = JSON.stringify(book)

  return {
    props: {
      bookJson
    }
  };
}
```

**utils/supabase-client.js**

```
export const getBook = async (id) => {
  const bookString = id
  let bookId = parseInt(bookString);
  
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('books')
    .select('id, name')
    .eq('id', bookId)

  if (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    throw error;
  }

  return data || [];
};
```

Comment: I’d like to use the ID from the url to query my table but at the moment I can only make it work if I hard code it. Thanks for asking.

Comment: You can access the route parameters through the [`getServerSideProps` context](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering), using `context.params.id` in your case (assuming you have `export async function getServerSideProps(context)`).

Comment: Ahhh brilliant! That's working perfectly thank you.

Comment: Why I got `404 This page could not be found.` ?

Comment: Turned out in next.config.js, pageExtensions was not configured right.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can access the route parameters through `getServerSideProps`'s context, using the `params` field.

> `params`: If this page uses a [dynamic route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes), `params` contains the route parameters. If the page name is `[id].js`, then `params` will look like `{ id: ... }`.
>
> — [Next.js, Data Fetching: getServerSideProps, Context parameter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter)

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const id = context.params.id // Get ID from slug `/book/1`
    
    // Rest of `getServerSideProps` code
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use the `query` field to access the route parameters. The difference is that `query` will also contain any query parameter passed in the URL.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const id = context.query.id // Get ID from slug `/book/1`
    // If routing to `/book/1?name=some-book`
    console.log(context.query) // Outputs: `{ id: '1', name: 'some-book' }`

    // ...
}
```

Comment: `context.query.accountId` was what I needed (to pull from a slug defined according to https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes). Thanks.